# Count how many times a value between x and y is present in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of 200 random numbers between 1 and 100 and need to find how many numbers between x and y are in the array. The ranges are between 1-10, 11-20, 21-30, and so on.

I have something like this

```
num_array = Array.new
200.times do
   num_array.push(rand(1...100))
end
print num_array
x = 1
y = 10
9.times do
  print num_array.count(x...y)   #<==
  x += 10
  y += 10
end
```

I want line 9 (the one that the arrow points to) to tell how many times numbers between x and y appear in the array. I know how to do it with more code, but I really want to do it with just this one or two lines.

Comment: `num_array.count(x...y)` counts the number of `(x...y)`'s (instances of `Range.new(x,y, true)`) there are in the array.

Answer (score 4):

[Array#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-count) with an argument and without a block checks whether the argument and the current element are equal. You'll need to pass a block and do some comparison, you may use [Comparable#between?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F), like this:

```
num_array.count { |el| el.between?(x,y) }
```

Comment: Nice use of `between?`, but I'd simplify it to `num_array.count { |el| el >= x && el <= y }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by` and group the values on the array according to (n / 10) * 10 which gives you the corresponding ten, e.g:

> (83 / 10) * 10 = 80

```
p Array.new(200) { rand(1..100) }.group_by { |i| (i / 10) * 10 }
{ 70=>[73, 77, 79, 70, 72, 78, 72, 75, 74, 71, 79, 70, 75, 78, 76, 70, 77, 76, 76, 70],
  80=>[81, 85, 81, 86, 88, 87, 85, 86, 80, 80, 82, 88, 89, 87, 87, 89, 86, 84, 82],
  60=>[68, 60, 64, 63, 64, 66, 69, 68, 66, 68, 67, 69, 61, 69, 62, 61, 66, 67, 69, 64, 65, 66, 68, 68, 60, 64, 69],
  30=>[31, 39, 39, 37, 32, 35, 31, 39, 30, 39, 33, 31, 36, 38, 30, 30, 36, 32, 39, 32, 31],
  20=>[22, 27, 24, 27, 25, 20, 23, 25, 27, 23, 24, 26, 27, 25, 25, 28, 20],
  40=>[42, 44, 47, 43, 45, 45, 41, 48, 41, 42, 45, 46, 45, 48, 47, 46, 45],
  90=>[92, 97, 92, 94, 94, 95, 93, 98, 93, 94, 94, 92, 96, 94, 91, 95, 94, 93, 99, 92, 99, 96, 91, 97, 99, 96, 94, 99],
  10=>[17, 13, 16, 18, 13, 19, 14, 16, 14, 12, 10, 15, 13, 16, 14, 13],
  50=>[58, 50, 54, 58, 57, 52, 53, 53, 56, 57, 50, 52, 55],
  0=>[4, 3, 7, 4, 2, 5, 9, 1, 4, 7, 8, 7, 3, 7, 9, 6, 6, 9, 6],
  100=>[100, 100, 100] }
```

Applying transform_values, it gets the total of elements per array for each element in the hash:

```
p Array.new(200) { rand(1..100) }.group_by { |i| (i / 10) * 10 }.transform_values(&:count)  
# {70=>20, 80=>19, 60=>27, 30=>21, 20=>17, 40=>17, 90=>28, 10=>16, 50=>13, 0=>19, 100=>3}
```

Note 0 is the key for the numbers between 1 and 10 (exclusive).

Answer (score 1):

**Additional:** You can also get which elements which are in between x & y and how many times those are repeated,

```
arr = num_array.group_by(&:itself).inject({}) { |m, (k,v)| m[k] = v.count if k.between?(x,y); m }
=> {5=>2, 6=>3, 8=>3, 2=>3, 10=>2, 7=>1, 4=>2, 9=>1}

arr.count
=> 8
```